# Wordpress get_post_meta() not working in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called 'work' in WP and need an email sent to an administrator every time a custom field 'socialmedia' has the value of 'yes'. The following code sends the mail fine but does not include the custom field value in the email:

```
function email_members($post_ID)  {
global $post;
if ( 'work' == get_post_type($post_ID) ){
    $social = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'socialmedia', true);
    mail('me@example.com', get_the_title($post_ID), $social);
}
return $post_ID;
}

add_action('publish_work', 'email_members');
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that there is a meta value for the key `socialmedia ` for that post?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `global $post` (doesn't appear to be used), and add some `var_dump();` lines to show you exactly what your variables contain, helping you to pin point the error.

Also, you mention that you want to send an email on if `socialmedia` is 'yes', but you have no check for that in your code?

```
function email_members($post_ID)  {

    var_dump($post_ID);
    var_dump(get_post_type($post_ID));

    if ( 'work' == get_post_type($post_ID) ){

        $social = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'socialmedia', true);
        var_dump($social);

        if ( $social === 'yes' ) {
            mail('me@example.com', get_the_title($post_ID), $social);
        }

    }

    die(); // Remove this after testing, it'll stop WP redirecting you so you can see what your variables contain.

    return $post_ID;
}

add_action('publish_work', 'email_members');
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the meta value before you send the email.

```
if( 'yes' == ($social = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'socialmedia', true)) )
{
  mail('me@example.com', get_the_title($post_ID), $social);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already pass $post_ID via function, what's the point of the global? How about ...

```
if(get_post_type($post_ID) === "work"){ 
    // do stuff 
}
```

Make sure it indeed returns "work" with ...

```
var_dump(get_post_type($post_ID);
```

Also, unless we know where you use the function. E.g in the loop, out of the loop? We can't really help much or well, I can't really help much.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. The function is used when a work post is published i.e. when the post is published, it should send an email only if 'socialmedia' has been marked as 'yes'